# Python fuction stereotyped

Tags: python

Class A has functionA has if. And functionA is repeated by 100 time in out.
In this case, it looks non scene to caluculate `if self.z....` each time in called by for in out.

```
Class A():
  def __ini__(self, z)
    self.z = z

  def functionA(self, a):
    if self.z == 1:
      b = zFunc1 * a
    elif self.z == 2:
      b = zFunc2 * a
  return b

  def out(self):
    for i in range(100):
      print(self.functionA(i))
```

So I'm looking for the way to fix functionA in `__ini__` like

```
Class A():
  def __ini__(self, z):
    self.z = z
    functionA < = FIX by (self.z = 2)
"""  
def functionA(self, a):
   b = zFunc2 * a
reuturn b
"""
```

Is there solution?

Comment: Honestly, no real idea what you’re asking…

Comment: I just reduce the time to caluculate if self.z.... 100 times to 1 time.....

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache…?

Comment: Please add an example of input/output. also, the constructor is usually named `__init__`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make `zFunc*` another class attribute decided in `__init__`:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, z):
        self.z = z
        self.z_func = zFunc1 if z == 1 else zFunc2

    def function_a(self, a):
        return self.z_func * a
```

In fact, in this example you don't even need `self.z` as an attribute at all.